# How to reduce value of variable in batch?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I need to reduce value of variable by 3 but it says Missing operand

```
:(1-3)
set /p speed=">> "
if %speed% geq 4 goto duzo
if %speed% leq 0 goto malo
set /a x=%x%-%speed%
```

I tried that too:

```
set /a speed=4-%speed%
```

Comment: Nowhere in the help file for the `SET` command does it say that a double equals is a valid operator. Where did you find this example on the Internet? You can simplify the assignment like this: `set /a speed-=4`.

Comment: There's no problem with your choice command, and tested on win10 it's okay.

Comment: @maxmarsz What did you do to make it working?  I just copied your lower case command and it worked fine.

Comment: I used big letters in arguments of choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting only a limited number of valid options, you should really consider using the `Choice` command. Unlike `Set /P` which allows for any or no entry, `Choice` will alert and prevent invalid input.

```bat
Set "velocidad=4"
Choice /C 123 /M "reduccion de velocidad: "
Set /A velocidad -= %ErrorLevel%
```

For usage information, enter `Choice /?` at the Command Prompt. And similarly for the `Set` command, `Set /?`.

Comment: When I add it program just stops as it comes and I cannot do anything to it

Comment: It won't work if you're still using the seventeen+ year old Operating System formerly known as Windows XP, as it wasn't part of that product. But I'm sure that you'd have mentioned that as part of your question proper, or at least use an appropriate title and/or tag to inform us you were using Windows XP if that was the case. Have you opened a Command Prompt window and entered `Choice /?` yet, if it works, the problem is elsewhere in something you haven't told us about, and therefore out of the scope of this question.

Comment: So Im working on windows 10 and yes I checkd the choice /? and it works. But when I use it in my program it just stops

Comment: @maxmarsz, there is absolutely nothing wrong with the three lines I've posted. Please [update the main body of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54010107/edit) to provide us with the actual code you're now having issues with. We cannot help you fix the problem if we don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
set /a speed=4-speed
```

When you use `/a`, you don't need `%` anymore. also you used `==` instead of `=`.

If you want x-speed, then it's:

```
set /a speed=x-speed
```